# How to bring caption to the "front layer" of image in LaTex?

Tags: captions, includegraphics

I have a Python plot saved as a PDF-file that I have imported to LaTex. Since the image has a thick white "border" (the plot itself doesn't "fill up" the whole image), it looks like there's quite a big gap between the plot/figure and the caption.

One solution is to crop the picture before uploading it, but since I would have to do this for a lot of plots, it would also be a bit cumbersome.

I have tried to reduce the gap by using `\vspace()`, but as the picture below shows, this ends up covering the caption.

Is it possible to circumvent the issue by bringing the caption to the front of the image somehow?

Below is: 1) Code for image, 2) imported packages, 3) sreenshot of output. I'm compiling in pdfLaTex.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
    \caption{\label{Perplexity}Perplexity core for LDA Model}
    \vspace*{-0.2cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{Images/Images/Perplexity.pdf}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc} % Selv tilføjet
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\babeltags{ru=russian, en=english}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, citestyle=apa, sorting=nyt ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Biblo.bib}
\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={2.5cm, 3cm}, vmargin={3cm, 3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,textfont=normal,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{float}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{etoolbox}\apptocmd\appendix{\pretocmd\section{\clearpage}{}{}}{}{}
\usepackage{subfiles} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\usepackage{topcapt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}

% Commands
\setstretch{1.25}
\newcommand{\margmod}[1]{\marginnote{\setstretch{.5}\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright\emph{#1}}}}

% Layout style
\linespread{1.5}
\fancyhead[L]{} 
\fancyhead[R]{\slshape \rightmark}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: you can trim the graphic `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,trim=0pt 0pt 0pt 1cm,clip]`

Comment: That did the job! Thanks a lot.